# I am kinda new to android and i have a question

Tags: android, graph

I actually made a realtime graph application and it is working perfectly.
Its a heart rate tracker where a sensor sends data via bluetooth to the application. the data gets plotted and printed as it changes.

my only problem is i want the data to continue being received even if the application is closed , like the application is running on the background .. 
Thank you.

Comment: You should implement a background service

Comment: https://medium.com/@harunwangereka/android-background-services-b5aac6be3f04

Comment: Use WorkManager for your requirement.